# Hide errobar under hollow points in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot data with errors. The data points are hollow diamonds and I do not want the part of the error showing inside the hollow diamonds. I just want it to show on outside the diamonds, leaving the inside empty. The code part I use is:

```
plt.errorbar(x=unknown['asd'], y=(unknown['dsa'])*-10, 
xerr=unknown['asderr'], yerr=(unknown['dsaerr']*-10), linestyle="None", fmt='D', markersize=7, 
ecolor='b', elinewidth=0.2, capsize=0.05, markerfacecolor='white', markeredgecolor='blue',
label=None, alpha=0.6)
```

I tried to use zorder :

```
plt.errorbar(x=unknown['asd'], y=(unknown['dsa'])*-10, 
xerr=unknown['asderr'], yerr=(unknown['dsaerr']*-10), linestyle="None", fmt='D', markersize=7, 
ecolor='b', elinewidth=0.2, capsize=0.05, markerfacecolor='white', markeredgecolor='blue',
label=None, alpha=0.6, zorder=1)

plt.plot(unknown['asd'], (unknown['dsa'])*-10, marker='D', markerfacecolor='none', markeredgecolor='blue', 
markeredgewidth=1, markersize=7, linestyle='None', zorder=2, alpha=0.6)
```

but I still see the errorbars passing through the hollow diamonds. Is there any quick way to make the errorbar line not shown under the hollow parts?

[image]

Comment: This is due to the alpha value of the plot, which reveals the lines below the marker. Either remove it or create a second plot on top of it, white, with `alpha=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `alpha` value set in the `plt.errorbar` call.

Here is a simpler example of what you're doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

markers_style = dict(fmt='D', markersize=20, markerfacecolor='white', markeredgecolor='blue')
lines_style = dict(ecolor='b', elinewidth=1, capsize=0.05)

plt.errorbar(x=10, y=10, xerr=0.5, yerr=0.5, **markers_style, **lines_style, alpha=0.6)
```

[image]

Removing `alpha=0.6`, you'll obtain the following figure

[image]

For some reason, you might want to keep the alpha value in the `errobar` call. In this case, to achieve the desired figure you'll have to create a second plot (`plt.plot` or `plt.scatter`) to *hide* the center of each hollow diamond.

```py
# [...]
plt.errorbar(x=10, y=10, xerr=0.5, yerr=0.5, **markers_style, **lines_style, alpha=0.6)

plt.plot(10, 10, marker='D', c="w", markersize=20)
```

[image]